# Печать двух страниц на одном листе

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как мне в Qt5 настроить так чтобы на одном листе A4 печатать два формата A5?

Просмотрел вроде всё что можно в классе [`QPrinter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html), не нашел там такого.

Вот так это выглядит если настраивать руками:

[image: print]